# Traversing an Array for user input with the goal of printing user output

Tags: c

[Screen shot showing problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5bj6.jpg)

I am trying to print output from user by traversing an array in using the C programming language.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
//my global variables
char day[15];
int dailyTrainCount[5];     // variable for daily train count
int trainTimeFrame[5], i;   // variable to daily train time frames and loop control

//begin program
int main()
{   
    printf("Welcome to TMS(TRAIN MANAGEMENT SYSTEM)\n");
    printf("Enter day of Operation\n");
    scanf("%s", day);//user input for day 
    printf("How many trains to operate on %s?(Trains shall not exceed 5)\n", 
     day);
    scanf("%d", &dailyTrainCount[5]);//daily train count variable

    //loop to ensure user enters no more than 5 trains per day
    while(dailyTrainCount[5] > 5){
          printf("Daily train count shall not exceed 5\n");
          printf("enter train count\n");
          scanf("%d", &dailyTrainCount[5]);
        }
    //show train menu to user
    printf("%d Train(s) will operate on %s\n",dailyTrainCount[5], day);
    printf("Available time frames\n");
    printf("(1):7AM-10PM\n");
    printf("(2):10AM-1PM\n");
    printf("(3):1PM-4PM\n");
    printf("(4):4PM-7PM\n");

    for(i=0; i<dailyTrainCount[5]; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter time frame for train #%d: \n",i+1);
        scanf("%d", &trainTimeFrame[5]);

    }

    //This loop is not traversing through the entire array, it only shows the last two input
    for(i=0; i<dailyTrainCount[5]; i++)
    {
        printf("Train #%d is set to time frame #%d\n",   // This is the print statement that
                                                         // is not producing the output as I intended
               dailyTrainCount[5], 
               trainTimeFrame[5]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

How can I produce output for the last for loop correctly? I am using Code Blocks. I've also tried changing all the arrays to [i], instead of [5].

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: This is not a [mcve]. You need to include the `#include`s and declarations for global variables too.

Comment: The for loop is not printing all of the arrays(dailyTrainCount & trainTimeFrame) via  user input.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't articulate what I was trying to convey, this stackoverflow requirement system is very extreme.

Comment: You should not be using `i` as a global variable.  It isn't clear that any of the arrays should be global either, especially as you only have `main()`.  You use file scope (`static`) variables to communicate between functions in a single file; you use file scope (non-static) variables to communicate between functions in multiple source files.  And you avoid both as much as possible, and limit the scope as much as possible.  All that said, it probably isn't causing your problem, but you should learn to treat globals as "bad".  Not always bad, but usually bad.

Comment: You are referencing outside the bounds of your array with your loop `while(dailyTrainCount[5] > 5){`; you are also repeatedly inputting to the same non-existent element of the array with `scanf("%d", &dailyTrainCount[5]);`.  You should probably be using an index variable (`i` perhaps) that iterates over the range `0` to `4` (`for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)` is idiomatic C).  Your input loop terminating condition doesn't make much sense even when you stop testing an out-of-bounds index.

Comment: See my attached image. I've pointed to the issue in red. The only issue I am having is the last printing lines. I'd like to print the other 2 time frame and train #'s. It's only printing the last user input.

Answer (score 2):

You have fundamental misunderstanding of the use of arrays in C:

```
int dailyTrainCount[5];     // variable for daily train count
...
    scanf("%d", &dailyTrainCount[5]);
```

`int dailyTrainCout[5];` declares an integer array with 5 elements. The valid indexes for those elements are `[0-4]`, C/C++ use *zero* based arrays. By assigning to `dailyTrainCount[5]`, you assign the input to the memory location 1-past the end of the `dailyTrainCount` array, invoking *Undefined Behavior*. (the defined execution of your program ceases at that point and anything from appearing to work normally to SegFaulting can occur) More fundamental, there will only be 1 `dailyTrainCount` so an array is not needed to begin with.

Next, while not an error, avoid the use of global variables. They are rarely required. Instead, declare your variables in the scope where they are needed and pass the variables as parameters to any function that needs to operate on their data.

Using `scanf` for input by new C programmers accounts for a significant percentage of of questions on this site. The misuse of `scanf` is common. The most common misuse is **failing to check the return**. The second most common is failing to account for what characters remain in the input buffer, unread, after a *matching failure*.

`scanf` can be used, if used correctly. This means **you** are responsible for checking the **return** of `scanf` *every time*. You must handle *three conditions*

1. `(return == EOF)` the user canceled input by generating a manual `EOF` by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+d</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl+z</kbd> on windows);
2. `(return < expected No. of conversions)` a *matching* or *input* failure occurred. For a *matching* failure you must account for every character left in your input buffer. (scan forward in the input buffer reading and discarding characters until a `'\n'` or `EOF` is found); and finally
3. `(return == expected No. of conversions)` indicating a successful read -- it is then up to you to check whether the input meets any additional criteria (e.g. positive integer, positive floating-point, within a needed range, etc..).

**Note:** after either a *matching failure* or successful read, you should empty the input buffer to ensure is it is prepared for the next user input, regardless of what function is used to take the input. For example, if you successfully use `scanf` to take integer input, but leave the trailing `'\n'` in the input buffer and then later attempt input with `fgets`, your input will fail and your buffer will contain the *empty-string* no matter how many characters the user types...

To facilitate using `scanf` correctly, you can use a short helper-function to empty the characters from `stdin` after each input. After each input, you simply call `getchar()` to read until the `'\n'` or `EOF` is found, e.g.

```
/* simple function to empty stdin */
void empty_stdin (void)
{
    int c = getchar();

    while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
        c = getchar();
}
```

Then, **at minimum**, you must validate the return of `scanf` matches the number of conversions specified in your *format-string*, e.g.

```
    char day[MAXDAY];
    int /* dailyTrainCount[5],*/ trainsperday,
        trainTimeFrame[MAXTRAIN], i = 0;

    fputs ("Welcome to TMS (TRAIN MANAGEMENT SYSTEM)\n\n"
            "  Enter day of Operation: ", stdout);
    if (scanf ("%14s", day) != 1) { /* VALIDATE EVERY INPUT - check return */
        fputs ("(user canceled day input.)\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    empty_stdin();  /* empty remaining characters in stdin */
```

(**note:** your `dailyTrainCount[]` array was replaced with a single integer variable `trainsperday` to make the change from *array of* `int` to single integer clear. `empty_stdin()` protects against any extraneous characters entered, such as the user entering `"Monday April 22, 2019"`. See what happens if you try that without emptying `stdin`...)

To fully validate each required input, you must check for, and adequately handle, all three conditions set forth above, e.g.

```
    for (;;) {  /* loop continually until valid input received */
        printf ("\n  How many trains to operate on %s?"
                " [1-5]: ", day);
        int rtn = scanf ("%d", &trainsperday);  /* save scanf return */
        if (rtn == EOF) {   /* handle EOF */
            fputs ("(user canceled day input.)\n", stderr);
            return 1;
        }
        empty_stdin();  /* empty remaining characters in stdin */
        if (rtn < 1)    /* if matching failure */
            fputs ("  (error: invalid integer input.)\n", stderr);
        else if (trainsperday < 0 || 5 < trainsperday)  /* out of range */
            fputs ("  (error: trainsperday exceeds 5.)\n", stderr);
        else            /* good input, break input loop */
            break;
    }
```

With that, you can accomplish filling your trains schedule while handling all input failures or values out of range, while still allowing the user to cancel input at any point and providing a graceful exiting of your program. A reworking of your code could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/*  my global variables - don't use them, declare in scope needed, but
 *  do #define any constants needed to avoid magic-numbers in your code
 */
#define MAXTRAIN 5
#define MAXDAY  15

/* simple function to empty stdin */
void empty_stdin (void)
{
    int c = getchar();

    while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
        c = getchar();
}

int main (void)
{   
    char day[MAXDAY];
    int /* dailyTrainCount[5],*/ trainsperday,
        trainTimeFrame[MAXTRAIN], i = 0;

    fputs ("Welcome to TMS (TRAIN MANAGEMENT SYSTEM)\n\n"
            "  Enter day of Operation: ", stdout);
    if (scanf ("%14s", day) != 1) { /* VALIDATE EVERY INPUT - check return */
        fputs ("(user canceled day input.)\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    empty_stdin();  /* empty remaining characters in stdin */

    for (;;) {  /* loop continually until valid input received */
        printf ("\n  How many trains to operate on %s?"
                " [1-5]: ", day);
        int rtn = scanf ("%d", &trainsperday);  /* save scanf return */
        if (rtn == EOF) {   /* handle EOF */
            fputs ("(user canceled day input.)\n", stderr);
            return 1;
        }
        empty_stdin();  /* empty remaining characters in stdin */
        if (rtn < 1)    /* if matching failure */
            fputs ("  (error: invalid integer input.)\n", stderr);
        else if (trainsperday < 0 || 5 < trainsperday)  /* out of range */
            fputs ("  (error: trainsperday exceeds 5.)\n", stderr);
        else            /* good input, break input loop */
            break;
    }
    /* show train menu to user */
    printf ("\n%d Train(s) will operate on %s\n\n"
            " Available time frames\n"
            "  (1) - 7AM-10PM\n"
            "  (2) - 10AM-1PM\n"
            "  (3) - 1PM-4PM\n"
            "  (4) - 4PM-7PM\n\n", trainsperday, day);

    while (i < trainsperday) {  /* use while, not for, to handle errors */
        printf ("  Enter time frame for train #%d: ", i + 1);
        int rtn = scanf ("%d", &trainTimeFrame[i]); /* save scanf return */
        if (rtn == EOF) {   /* handle EOF */
            fputs ("(user canceled day input.)\n", stderr);
            return 1;
        }
        empty_stdin();  /* empty remaining characters in stdin */
        if (rtn < 1)    /* if matching failure */
            fputs ("  (error: invalid integer input, valid input [1-4].)\n",
                    stderr);
        else if (trainTimeFrame[i] < 0 || 4 < trainTimeFrame[i]) /* valid? */
            fputs ("  (error: invalid time frame, valid input [1-4].)\n",
                    stderr);
        else            /* good input, now increment i */
            i++;
    }

    /* output train schedule */
    printf ("\nTrain Schedule:\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < trainsperday; i++)
        printf ("  Train #%d is set to time frame #%d\n",
                i + 1, trainTimeFrame[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** the use of a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop when filling the timeframes for each train. If a `for` is used and a failure occurs, you cannot recover. Using a `while` and only incrementing your counter on valid input provides a solution)

Now any time you write a program that takes input -- go try and break it. Enter invalid input on purpose to exercise the error handling of your code. If you break it, fix it and try again. After you have tried all the invalid input you can think of, have a cat step on the keyboard. If it passes all test, you can be reasonably sure you have covered  the most likely misuse scenarios your users will provide.

**Example Use/Output**

With intentional invalid input for that purpose.

```
$ ./bin/trainsperday
Welcome to TMS (TRAIN MANAGEMENT SYSTEM)

  Enter day of Operation: Tuesday April 23, 2019

  How many trains to operate on Tuesday? [1-5]: Ten Trains on Tuesday
  (error: invalid integer input.)

  How many trains to operate on Tuesday? [1-5]: 7
  (error: trainsperday exceeds 5.)

  How many trains to operate on Tuesday? [1-5]: 3

3 Train(s) will operate on Tuesday

 Available time frames
  (1) - 7AM-10PM
  (2) - 10AM-1PM
  (3) - 1PM-4PM
  (4) - 4PM-7PM

  Enter time frame for train #1: 7AM-10PM
  (error: invalid time frame, valid input [1-4].)
  Enter time frame for train #1: 5
  (error: invalid time frame, valid input [1-4].)
  Enter time frame for train #1: 3
  Enter time frame for train #2: 1
  Enter time frame for train #3: 2

Train Schedule:

  Train #1 is set to time frame #3
  Train #2 is set to time frame #1
  Train #3 is set to time frame #2
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Glad to help. C isn't difficult -- but the devil is in the details. You control every byte of memory with no training wheels. If you can always answer "what is at byte - X?" of each block of memory or input stream -- you are half-way there. There is a lot to learn with C, so *slow down*, enjoy the learning. If you learn C, it will make you a better programmer regardless of what language you ultimately end up writing in -- just due to the low-level understanding it provides. Good luck with your coding!

Comment: What is your method when coding? Do you write the logic on paper with pseudocode before actually typing anything?

Comment: It depends. If it is logic that I'm unsure of, I do pull out a 8.5x11 sheet of paper and a pencil (and eraser) and think through the problem writing down what I need to accomplish. This is particularly helpful when learning linked-lists and inserting nodes. Drawing boxes for the nodes and then using arrows for the pointers to connect them lets you visualize what needs to be done. You just code each step to follow what you have done on paper. Other times, if I can hold the sequence in my head, I just code from there. The more you do it -- the less paper you use `:)` (just like math)